# NameNotFoundException in Jboss when connecting to database through JNDI

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, datasource, jndi

I am using JBoss 4.3.0. I am trying to create a datasource in the server to connect to MS SQL server.

I created a file **myapp-mssql-ds.xml** and placed it inside *C:\jboss-4.3.0\server\myapps\deploy* directory.

The following are the contents of the file :

```
   <datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
<jndi-name>jdbc/MyDatasource</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://urlhere</connection-url>

<driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
<user-name>myuser</user-name>
<password>mypassword</password>


<min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>70</max-pool-size>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>

 </local-tx-datasource>
  </datasources>
```

and in the Java code I access it the following way

```
     DataSource dataSource;
     DAOFactory instance = null;

    String url ="jdbc/MyDatasource";
    try {
        dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(url);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new DAOConfigurationException(
            "DataSource '" + url + "' is missing in JNDI.", e);
    }

      instance = new DataSourceDAOFactory(dataSource);
```

Finally, I get this exception,

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyDatasource not bound

Am I missing something ? Do I have to make any other entries elsewhere ?

Comment: Have you looked at your server startup logs? Is the server able to create the datasource successfully? What's the name of the datasource that appears in the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JNDI name for the JDBC data source is bound relative to the `java:/` context ([see the docs here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connectors_on_JBoss-Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html)), so you just need to change `String url = "jdbc/MyDatasource"` to `String url = "java:jdbc/MyDatasource"`.

Alternatively, you can configure your data source with the `use-java-context` property set to `false` and not need to worry about prefixing the JNDI name with `java:`.